# TypeScript: Is it possible to define new class members using decorators?

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
function Getter(target: any, key: string): void {
  let getter = () => this[key];
  /*  create "foobar" property from "_foobar" */
  Object.defineProperty(target, removeUnderscores(key), {
    get: getter,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
}

class Foo {
   @Getter 
   private _foobar: string;
   constructor() {
      this._foobar = "Hello World" // OK
      console.log(this.foobar) // Compiler error
   }
}

let foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.foobar) // Compiler error
```

I guess it's possible to make `_foobar` public and rename it to `foobar` to avoid creating new property names, but trying to modify that property externally won't cause compile-time error, it should cause a run-time error when it's modified internally or externally.

Comment: Just to put it out there, you can define getters in TypeScript using `public get foobar() { return this._foobar; }`. The compiler's not going to evaluate your code and figure out what the result of `removeUnderscores(key)` is, so there's no way to make what you're trying to do here work.

Answer (score 0):

> console.log(this.foobar) // Compiler error

You cannot remove this compiler error based on the current semantics of a TypeScript decorator infrastructure.